# Implementing google map in django code

Tags: python, django, json, google-maps, dictionary

I have to implement a google map in django. Basically in that map i have to show the area's depending upon market sales. Depending upon the market sales i have to group the zips in to 5 equal groups i.e 1-20% sales will be 1st group, 21-40% sales will be the second group... like this. 5 groups will have there own color in the map while displaying.

I have longitude, latitude, number polygon, sales percentage grouping as input to the map

What should be the best way to proceed. Is there any code example using which i can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the Google Maps API on the client side.  It isn't really a Django specific issue.  You could do it by writing some javascript for the client template view that uses the longitude, latitude etc that you've got from your webserver.  Have a look at this question:

[Add Google Maps to my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934405/how-can-i-add-google-my-maps-api-on-my-website)

You can populate your template with the latitude/longitude values from the dictionary you pass into the render_to_response call that creates your html page.